VS Code venv on Mac suddenly stopped working, possibly not activating the environment correctly
I always use python within a venv, this typically works everyday. In VS Code I use .code-workspace to structure my projects for dedvelopment and each sub project have their own venv typically named "env" for simplicity and repeatability.
Just now after the latest MacOS update, venv environments stopped working in the integrated VS Code terminal. The environment "env" is selected in vscode python interpreter setting, and a new vscode terminal opens correctly and looks to have been activated, as I see "(env) fredriklundstrom".
The look as if they are activated but running "python" doesn't work - I get a command not found.
In Terminal app however, it still works just as before.
Anyone know what has happened or experienced the same? How to troubleshoot?
Using homebrew, venv, python (normally 3.9, 3.10, 3.12, or 3.13), VS Code, MacOS.
VS Code version: 1.96.0
MacOS Seqouia 15.2
